# Jmeter Response Array Extraction

Tags: json, regex, api, jmeter, response

Example I'm getting this response, and I want extract/validate the data response, is there's a way to remove the array or will return me the second screenshot?
{"success":true,"data":["BUSHIDO-GENERAL","QA","QA3","QA5"]}

Screenshot:

[image]

Expected Result: I just want to validate/extract individual data inside the array
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[JSOM Assertion][1]` or [JSON JMESPath Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Assertion) to validate the JSON responses. Add one of them as a child element to the request element and configure the assertion to validate the expected values.

[image]

You can use the post processors to extract the values from responses. You may use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) to extract the values from JSON responses.

[image]